# git diff not working with Word document, --intent-to-add, and pandoc diff driver

Tags: git, diff, pandoc, git-diff, git-add

Several tutorials ([[1]](http://blog.martinfenner.org/2014/08/25/using-microsoft-word-with-git/), [[2]](https://github.com/vigente/gerardus/wiki/Integrate-git-diffs-with-word-docx-files), [[3]](http://hrishioa.github.io/tracking-word-documents-with-git/)) that can be found on the internet suggest the following configuration for diffing Word documents tracked by `git`.

1. Configure a "pandoc" diff driver with the following settings:

   ```
   [diff "pandoc"]
       textconv=pandoc --to=markdown
       prompt = false
   ```
2. Add the following to your `.gitattributes` file:

   ```
   *.docx diff=pandoc
   ```

This seems to work fine except when trying to diff an untracked Word document after indicating intent to add it to the git repository. Does anyone know why this isn't working in this case?

Here are the steps to reproduce, assuming the following configuration detailed above.

1. Create a Word document in a git repository

   ```
   touch my_document.docx
   ```
2. Open the file in Microsoft Word, add some content to the Word document (*e.g*, the characters "asdf"), and save it
3. Indicate your intent to add the document

   ```
   git add -N my_document.docx
   ```
4. Try to see the diff:

   ```
   git diff my_document.docx
   #> couldn't parse docx file
   #> fatal: unable to read files to diff
   ```

With `git` version 2.17.1 on macOS, I end up with a "fatal: unable to read files to diff" error. However, just adding the file to the index and then running `git diff --cached` results in the following diff:

```
diff --git a/my_document.docx b/my_document.docx
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..17f1b0d
--- /dev/null
+++ b/my_document.docx
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+asdf
```

Why doesn't the diff driver work with `git add -N`?

Comment: it said '#> couldn't parse docx file' because that's probably not right docx markup, what did you expect? The latter command run the file through regular `diff`, hence doing text comparison.

Comment: @orhtej2 Ah, thanks. I see. So this is ultimately due to the difference between `pandoc --to=markdown /dev/null` and `touch my_document.docx && pandoc --to=markdown my_document.docx`. Do you want to expand your comment into an answer?

Comment: Seems like this is a corner-case misfeature in pandoc, completely empty documents making it barf unavoidably is simply bad behavior.

Comment: @jthill Yes, perhaps. I opened [an issue](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/4717). We'll see what they say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is ultimately due to the fact that `pandoc --to=markdown /dev/null/` correctly returns nothing without erroring out, whereas `pandoc --to=markdown a/my_document.docx` errors out just in case `a/my_document.docx` is an empty file.

So in the case where you've added `my_document.docx` to the index for the first time and then run `git diff --cached` to compare the index to HEAD, the comparison will be against `/dev/null`, and everything will work just fine.

However, in the case where you've indicated your intent to add a new file, `my_document.docx`, with `git add -N`, an empty file with the same name will be added to the index. In this case, `pandoc` will error out when trying to convert the empty file in the index to Markdown.